# Bootstrap 3 + Wordpress + Jquery Conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have build a custom bootstrap 3 theme for wordpress. It's almost ready to go except I have the following error which is causing some slideshow plugs ins not to work.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function
```

I have been told this is a sort of issue with Jquery and no conflict mode? I really don't know much about Jquery and hope someone can provide a step by step / easy solution for me to implement. Any help would be greatly appreciated. This one issue is holding up going live with this theme :(

Link to site: http://www.streetfiredesigns.com/testsite/

Comment: why adding two files of same jQuery library ? .Remove one and Change `$` with `jQuery`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `$` and change them to `jQuery`

Comment: HI, thanks for the reply. What file does this need to happen in? Sorry really not knowledgeable in this code

Comment: Well, in all the files you are having the conflict in. In this case this would be the `.js` file in the bootstrap.